# nerdctl DNS timeout on Windows

Tags: networking, rancher, nerdctl

We just installed Rancher Desktop 1.4.1 (nerdctl v 0.20.0) on Windows 10 and we seem to have a problem pulling images and logging into a registry:

```
nerdctl pull alpine
docker.io/library/alpine:latest: resolving      |--------------------------------------|
elapsed: 9.9 s                   total:   0.0 B (0.0 B/s)
INFO[0010] trying next host                              error="failed to do request: Head \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.167.172:53: read udp 192.168.167.172:47744->192.168.167.172:53: i/o timeout" host=registry-1.docker.io
FATA[0010] failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/alpine:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.167.172:53: read udp 192.168.167.172:47744->192.168.167.172:53: i/o timeout
```

Trying to `login` results in similar errors:

```
nerdctl --debug-full login registry-1.docker.io
/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-rancher-desktop: source: line 5: can't open '/etc/rancher/desktop/credfwd': No such file or directory
Enter Username: myusername
Enter Password:
DEBU[0030] Ignoring hosts dir "/etc/containerd/certs.d"  error="stat /etc/containerd/certs.d: no such file or directory"
DEBU[0030] Ignoring hosts dir "/etc/docker/certs.d"      error="stat /etc/docker/certs.d: no such file or directory"
DEBU[0030] len(regHosts)=1
ERRO[0040] failed to call tryLoginWithRegHost            error="failed to call rh.Client.Do: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.167.172:53: read udp 192.168.167.172:36590->192.168.167.172:53: i/o timeout" i=0
FATA[0040] failed to call rh.Client.Do: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.167.172:53: read udp 192.168.167.172:36590->192.168.167.172:53: i/o timeout
```

It looks like `nerdctl` is having problems resolving hostnames. It always times-out after 10 seconds.

Is there a way to explicitly configure hostname resolution in Rancher or nerdctl?

Any help would be appreciated.